# Can't install software because "No module named 'debconf'" error in apt/dpkg

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, debconf

I get this error message every time I try to install any app.

```
Setting up apt-listchanges (3.8) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/tmp.agLdMrHHO6.aptlc/debconf-helper.py", line 6, in <module>
import debconf
ImportError: No module named 'debconf'
dpkg: error processing package apt-listchanges (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
apt-listchanges
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 7):

You are getting this error because your Python 3 installation is broken. It can not import the `debconf` module. You can confirm this by trying the following:

```
$ python3 -m debconf
/usr/bin/python3: No module named debconf
```

If this is the case, you should check that the `debconf.py` file exists in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and that this directory is on your `sys.path`.

In the past, I've experienced this problem when I installed a custom Python interpreter. Make sure that the command `type python3` returns `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: I had to uninstall the python version I had installed from sources to get rid of this message.

Comment: what if it doesn't exist in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` ?

Comment: Than there is probably more broken than just your Python installation. `apt` depends on `debconf` which depends on `python3-debconf` which provides the missing `debconf.py`. So you will need to install/reinstall all those packages, but you cannot do this if `apt` isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of

```
type python3
```

should be

```
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
```

If it isn't:

Edit file

```
/etc/profile
```

Remove

```
/usr/local/bin:
```

from path after first 'if' condition

Reboot

It's done now.

Works on RPi jessy to stretch upgrade

Comment: Doesn't that effect other bins'?